# created a linked list to insert an array in it, but it's not giving desired output

Tags: c++

I had created a program to create a linked list and insert an array in it. But it's not giving the desired output, may be the problem is in display function

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//node 
class node {
    public:
    int data;
    node *next;
} *head = nullptr;

//function to insert array in linkedlist
void create(int A[], int n) {
    node *head = new node;
    node *temp;
    node *last;
    head->data = A[0];
    head->next = nullptr;
    last = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        //temp is an temporary variable which creates each time and last remebers its position
        temp = new node;
        temp->data = A[i];
        cout << temp->data << endl;
        temp->next = nullptr;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}

//function to display linked list which can access head because it is global
void display() { 
    node *p = head;
    while (p != nullptr) {
        cout << p->data << endl;
        p = p->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    int A[] = {1, 6, 9, 4, 5, 6};
    node *head;
    create(A, 6);
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe I understand something wrong like to add display function in class. But I had never seen a class pointer having functions.

This is my first linked list program. If you could share some good info about it please do, thank you

Comment: `node *head= new node;` declares a new local variable that hides the global variable `head`. See e.g. https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/variable-shadowing-name-hiding/

Comment: I'd suggest forgetting that C-style arrays exist in the language and instead always use either [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Would you mind adding actual and expected output?

Comment: @JesperJuhl not to mention providing `node` with a constructor, destructor, and usefully in this case, an append (or prepend) member function. C++ makes this possible. What's shown is basically C with iostream.

Comment: It's never too soon to stop using global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple variables named `head` being used for different purposes. You have a global variable `head`, which your `display()` function uses, but your `create()` function does not populate. `create()` populates a local variable named `head` instead, which *shadows* the global variable. `display()` never sees the created list. And `main()` has its own local variable named `head`, which is not being used for anything at all.

Get rid of the global variable. Make `create()` return the list it creates. And then make `main()` pass that list to `display()`.

Try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//node 
class node {
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
};

//function to insert array in linkedlist
node* create(int A[], int n) {
    node *head = nullptr;
    node **p = &head;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        *p = new node{ A[i], nullptr };
        p = &((*p)->next);
    }
    return head;
}

//function to display linked list
void display(const node *head) { 
    node *p = head;
    while (p != nullptr) {
        cout << p->data << endl;
        p = p->next;
    }
}

//function to destroy linked list
void destroy(node *head) {
    node *p = head;
    while (p != nullptr) {
        node *next = p->next;
        delete p;
        p = next;
    }
} 

int main() {
    int A[] = {1, 6, 9, 4, 5, 6};
    node *head = create(A, 6);
    display(head);
    destroy(head);
    return 0;
}
```